# Error? An open subset of $\mathbb R^p$ is connected if and only if it can be expressed as the union of two disjoint non-empty open sets.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I believe the book which I am reading has a printing error. One of the lemmas reads like this

An open subset of $\mathbb R^p$ is connected $\iff$if it can be expressed as the union of two disjoint non-empty open sets.

I think, instead, the statement should be :
An open subset of $\mathbb R^p$ is **disconnected** $\iff$if it can be expressed as the union of two disjoint non-empty open sets.

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. Alternatively, there is a "not" missing.

Comment: That sounds correct but is not really, consider $p=1$ and $[0,1] \setminus \{\frac12\}$. This cannot be expressed as the union of two non-empty disjoint open sets. I think it needs to say **can be covered** by two disjoint open sets

Comment: @DanielFischer What about my counterexample?

Comment: @AlexR "An open subset of $\mathbb{R}^p$"; otherwise, one would consider relatively open sets.